# Regarding cross complitaion in java

Tags: java, teamcity

I have my project on which is need to be build on jdk 1.5 and rite now I am using jdk 1.7
can u please advise the command line parameters that I should add so that myy java project
to compile and build  on jdk 1,5 itself still i am using jdk 1.7 what i have tried is ...

```
javac -source 1.5 -target 1.7
```

I am getting this error below..

```
    [Step 1/2] Ant output
[12:52:04][Ant output] Error: Could not find or load main class javac
```

what my basic concern is that i have my teamcity server is runnig on jdk 1.7 and my project should be build on jdk 1.5 so for that in teamcity we can specify external command line parameters for code to run explicitly on jdk .1.5 , Please advise

Comment: To run under 1.5 the _target_ should be 1.5. Unfortunately also the _source_ as the differences are too large between the versions. In fact you should compile with a JDK 1.5. For instance in a later version the zip API had an additional encoding parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Java 5.0 `javac` then you can only build Java 5.0 source code.  Once compiled this code can run on Java 5.0 or Java 7 or Java 9

I suspect the default command line options are what you want, and if not you will have to upgrade your JDK.

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7 can u pls advise in my build process I want to build it by using jdk 1.65 once how can i specify this

Comment: Do you mean 1.6.0_05?  There was no `1.65`. `1.6.0_05` is really old so I suggest updating your version of Java 6.  The most reliable way to to build for a particular version of Java is to use the JDK for that version.  You can try playing with the versions, but this won't prevent you from using a class or method which was added to a newer version, you can specify a class path as well but by the time you do this, it is much simpler just to use the real version.